# Calling uipangesture from uitableviewcell class when tapped a cell

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uipangesturerecognizer, didselectrowatindexpath

I am using [ABMenuTableViewCell](https://github.com/alexbumbu/ABMenuTableViewCell)  tableview controller in my application. I want to call `didSelectRowAtIndexPat`h when i swipe a `UITableViewCell`.

Right now `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` only execute when I tap on a cell, I want to call it even when I swipe it. here is my `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` and `cellforRowAtIndexPath` methods code.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
        UILabel *likes;
        UILabel *downloads;
        static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
        ABMenuTableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

        if (cell == nil)
        {
            cell = [[ABMenuTableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
            arrow = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"acc_arrow_back.png"]];
            arrow.frame = CGRectMake(300, 50, 5, 12);
            arrow.image = [arrow.image imageWithRenderingMode:UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysTemplate];
            [arrow setTintColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:(191/255.0) green:(2/255.0) blue:(6/255.0) alpha:1]];
            [cell.contentView addSubview:arrow];

UIImageView *likes_img = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"social.png"]];
            likes_img.frame = CGRectMake(15, 80, 15, 15);
            likes_img.image = [likes_img.image imageWithRenderingMode:UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysTemplate];
            [likes_img setTintColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:(191/255.0) green:(2/255.0) blue:(6/255.0) alpha:1]];
            [cell.contentView addSubview:likes_img];

            likes =[[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(33, 78, 80, 20)];
            likes.tag = 1001;    // set a tag for this View so you can get at it later
            likes.textColor=[UIColor darkGrayColor];
            likes.font=[UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:10.0f];
            likes.text=[[rssOutputData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]xmllikes];
            [cell.contentView addSubview:likes];
            cell.detailTextLabel.textColor = [UIColor darkGrayColor];

            UIImageView *downloads_img = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"download.png"]];
            downloads_img.frame = CGRectMake(55, 79, 15, 15);
            downloads_img.image = [downloads_img.image imageWithRenderingMode:UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysTemplate];
            [downloads_img setTintColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:(191/255.0) green:(2/255.0) blue:(6/255.0) alpha:1]];
            [cell.contentView addSubview:downloads_img];

            downloads =[[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(73, 78, 80, 20)];
            downloads.tag = 1002;    // set a tag for this View so you can get at it later
            downloads.textColor=[UIColor darkGrayColor];
            downloads.font=[UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:10.0f];
            downloads.text=[[rssOutputData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]xmldownloads];
            [cell.contentView addSubview:downloads];
            cell.detailTextLabel.textColor = [UIColor darkGrayColor];
        }
        else
        {
            // use viewWithTag to find lblNombre in the re-usable cell.contentView
            likes = (UILabel *)[cell.contentView viewWithTag:1001];
            downloads = (UILabel *)[cell.contentView viewWithTag:1002];

        }
        cell.textLabel.text = [[rssOutputData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]xmlsinger];
        cell.detailTextLabel.text = [[rssOutputData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]xmltitle];
        // custom menu view
        NSString *nibName = @"ABCellMailStyleMenuView";
        ABCellMenuView *menuView = [ABCellMenuView initWithNib:nibName bundle:nil];
        menuView.delegate = self;
        menuView.indexPath = indexPath;
        cell.rightMenuView = menuView;
        return cell;
}


   - (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
   {
            [tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];
   }
```

And these are the methods in cell class 
`- (BOOL)gestureRecognizerShouldBegin:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer` and 
`- (void)swipeGesture:(UIPanGestureRecognizer *)gesture`
here is when i swipe
[image]

Comment: can you please add your screen shot of how you `UITableView` shown?

Comment: Why do you want that? Isn't the point of having `ABMenuTableViewCell` to show menu on swipe?

Comment: @JakubVano thanks for reply. yes it is showing but right now it is showing when a cell is swiped not on tap. i want to call both things together like if i swipe it will also call didSelectRowAtIndexPath

Comment: because i tested `ABMenuTableViewCell`, and its working fine. i think there is some content overlapping so.

Comment: @None i added a screenshot

Comment: @VixHunk here you confused me - do you want to show menu on both tap and swipe, or do you want to select the cell on both swipe and tap?

Comment: @VixHunk, i think your swipe working fine. just need to show selected tab once you swiped. right ?

Comment: @JakubVano yes exactly i want to show menu on both that is exactly what i want to do. thanks for understanding

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can modified `swipeGesture` method will following code. it will show `UITableViewCell` as `selected` once you perform swipe operation.

```
- (void)swipeGesture:(UIPanGestureRecognizer *)gesture {
    if (gesture.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan) {
        NSInteger direction;

        // find swipe direction
        CGPoint velocity = [gesture velocityInView:self];
        if (velocity.x > 0) {
            // towards right - hide menu view
            direction = ABMenuUpdateHideAction;
        }
        else {
            // towards left - show menu view
            direction = ABMenuUpdateShowAction;
        }


        UITableView* tableView = (UITableView*)self.superview.superview;

        CGPoint swipeLocation = [gesture locationInView:tableView];
        NSIndexPath *swipedIndexPath = [tableView indexPathForRowAtPoint:swipeLocation];

        [tableView selectRowAtIndexPath:swipedIndexPath animated:NO scrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionNone];


        [self updateMenuView:direction animated:YES];
    }
}
```

Hope this help  you.

Comment: Thank You this one helped a lot but still menu doesn't open when i tap but now opened menu closes when i tap on another cell

Comment: so you dont want to closed your previous swiped cell right?

Comment: yes i do want to close that. but i also want to open menu when i tap a cell

Comment: ok if that is not possible can you just tell me how can i call a method of my viewcontroller when that menu appears!

Comment: Using `Delegate`, you can call method of `UIViewController`.

Comment: you can open menu while tapping on cell as well/. but you need to create method in side `UITableVIewCell` and write the code in that method that is now available in `- (void)swipeGesture:(UIPanGestureRecognizer *)gesture`. and called that method while `didSelectedRowAtIndexPath called.

Comment: Thank You so much i figured it out further. Thanks for giving me proper idea what to do.

Answer (score 1):

As you are trying to achieve behaviour not supported by `ABMenuTableViewCell`, you will need to edit it's source:

Add `_tapGesture` and `_menuVisible` instance variables:

```
@implementation ABMenuTableViewCell {
    CGRect _rightMenuViewInitialFrame;
    UIPanGestureRecognizer *_swipeGesture;
    UITapGestureRecognizer *_tapGesture;
    BOOL _menuVisible;
}
```

Implement `-tapGesture:` method:

```
- (void) tapGesture:(UITapGestureRecognizer*)gesture {
if (_menuVisible)
    [self updateMenuView:ABMenuUpdateHideAction animated:YES];
else
    [self updateMenuView:ABMenuUpdateShowAction animated:YES];
}
```

Add `UITapGestureRecognizer` inside `-commonInit` method:

```
- (void) commonInit {
    _swipeGesture = [[UIPanGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(swipeGesture:)];
    _swipeGesture.delegate = self;
    [self addGestureRecognizer:_swipeGesture];

    _tapGesture = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(tapGesture:)];
    _tapGesture.delegate = self;
    [self addGestureRecognizer:_tapGesture];
}
```

Update `_menuVisible` inside `-updateMenuView:animated:`:

```
- (void)updateMenuView:(ABMenuUpdateAction)action animated:(BOOL)animated {
    ...

    switch (action) {
        case ABMenuUpdateShowAction:
            menuNewFrame = CGRectMake(CGRectGetWidth(self.contentView.frame) - initialWidth, .0, initialWidth, CGRectGetHeight(self.contentView.frame));
            _menuVisible = YES;
            break;

        case ABMenuUpdateHideAction:
            menuNewFrame = CGRectMake(CGRectGetWidth(self.contentView.frame), .0, .0, CGRectGetHeight(self.contentView.frame));
            _menuVisible = NO;
            break;

        default:
            break;
    }
    ...
}
```

You won't be able to select cells, but as I understand it, you don't want to.

Comment: Thanks you. i checked this code but it opens menu first time then i had to close it by swiping it. but second time i tap it wont open third time wont open then on forth attempt menu opens again

Comment: I edited my answer, so that it also hides menu on tap

Answer (score 0):

If you want the method to be called when swiping the cell, you should be using a `UISwipeGestureRecognizer` and not a `UIPanGestureRecognizer`.

In your `viewDidLoad:`, set up the gesture recognizer.

```
// Create a left swipe gesture recognizer
UISwipeGestureRecognizer *recognizer = [[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleSwipeLeft:)];
[recognizer setDirection:(UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionLeft)];

// Add it to the table view
[self.tableView addGestureRecognizer:recognizer];
```

Handle the swipe.

```
- (void)handleSwipeLeft:(UISwipeGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer
{
    // Get location of the swipe
    CGPoint location = [gestureRecognizer locationInView:self.tableView];

    //Get the corresponding index path within the table view
    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForRowAtPoint:location];

    // Check if index path is valid
    if (indexPath)
    {
        // Select the cell at the indexPath
        [self.tableView selectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:NO scrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionNone];
    }
}
```

That should call the `tableView: didSelectRowAtIndexPath:` method.

Comment: Thanks i tried this one but it doesn't even trigger handleSwipeLeft method

Comment: Did you try setting the `delaysTouchesBegan` property to YES?